# Composable with Flow from Room Db not updating from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, broadcastreceiver, android-room

I have an app where the users screen is made up of a list of objects from the DB. Those objects are updated in the background using a BroadcastReceiver that run business logic code periodically as well as in a separate ViewModel. The composable updates correctly on first compose and when the updates are made by the VM but NOT when the Db is updated in the receiver. I know that the receiver is firing and updating the DB correctly, they just never make their way to the app when it's in the foreground.

Aside from it being a separate service/receiver the only other difference between the VM and receiver code is that the receiver uses a separate instance of the Db created when it runs.

I've removed the extra fields and code that maps everything to the UI for brevity.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

The Entity

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"participantId", "studyId"})
public class Participant {
    //******
    //Required parameters
    //******
    @NonNull @ColumnInfo
    public String participantId;

    @NonNull @ColumnInfo
    public String studyId;

    @ColumnInfo
    public LocalDateTime  timeLastUploaded;

    public Participant(@NonNull String participantId, @NonNull String studyId) {
        this.participantId = participantId;
        this.studyId = studyId;
    }
}
```

The Dao

```
@Dao
interface ParticipantDao {
    @Insert
     fun insertParticipant(participant: Participant): Long

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
     fun updateParticipant(participant: Participant)

    @Delete
     fun deleteParticipant(participant: Participant)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Participant WHERE participantId LIKE :participantId")
     fun getParticipantByParticipantId(participantId: String): Participant


    @Query("SELECT * FROM Participant ORDER BY participantId ASC")
     fun getAllParticipants(): Flow<List<Participant>>
}
```

The Db helper

```
interface DatabaseHelper {
    override fun getAllParticipants(): Flow<List<Participant>> = 
        appDatabase.participantDao().getAllParticipants()
}

class AppDatabaseHelper(private val appDatabase: AppDatabase) : DatabaseHelper{
    override fun getAllSensors(): Flow<List<Sensor>> = flow {
        emit(appDatabase.sensorDao().getAllSensors())
    }

    override fun getAllParticipants(): Flow<List<Participant>> = flow {
        emit(appDatabase.participantDao().getAllParticipants())
    }

}
```

The composable

```
@Composable
fun Users(navController: NavHostController, usersVM: UsersVM){
    val uiState by usersVM.uiState.collectAsState()
    usersVM.navController = navController

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        if(uiState.participants.isNotEmpty()) {
            for(participant in uiState.participants) {
                //Display the users
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The VM

```
class UsersVM(private val appDB: AppDatabase): ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(UsersUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<UsersUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    var participants: List<Participant> = listOf()
    private var appDBHelper: AppDatabaseHelper = AppDatabaseHelper(appDB)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            appDBHelper.getAllParticipants()
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .catch { e ->
                    Timber.e("fillUsersList getAllParticipants ex: ${e.message}")
                }.collect {
                    participants = it
                    _uiState.value = UsersUiState(participants)
                }
        }
    }
}

data class UsersUiState(val participants: List<Participant> = mutableListOf(), val sensors: List<Sensor> = mutableListOf())
```

In the BroadcaseReceiver

```
override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
    android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()
    Timber.d("Sync alarm +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    if (p0 != null) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            appDB = Room.databaseBuilder(
                p0,
                AppDatabase::class.java, "app-database"
            ).build()

            val participant = appDB.participantDao().getParticipantByParticipantId("ID Goes Here")

            if (participant != null) {
                //Do some stuff here
                
                //Done doing stuff successfully
                participant.participantId = LocalDateTime.now()
                appDB.participantDao().updateParticipant(participant)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a singleton instance of the database because it is the instance that triggers its flows to do a requery each time after it does an update. All the Room tutorials show how it is created as a singleton.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I'll report back here once I have a chance to make that change.

Answer (score 0):

As Tenfour04 pointed out, the issue was that updates are driven by the instance of the db doing the updates. I moved to a Singleton and it is working as expected. I found this helpful: https://medium.com/@stephenmuindi241/singleton-pattern-in-room-database-566c250196aa